# System.Data.ODBC fail reading data from Filemaker database C#

Tags: c#, odbc, filemaker

Hello and thanks for reading.  We have a Filemaker database that we would like to read using **System.Database.ODBC** - We successfully connect and also, if we want to update, delete, or insert, it works fine using **command.ExecuteNonQuery()**, the problem arises when we try to read data, in other words, when we try to get a recordset... I did notice it reads successfully from the database using **command.ExecuteReader()**, the problem arises when it tries to loop through the columns and rows, specifically when it tries to get the column name, datatype, etc... in other words, the metadata.

for example, in the following query: "**SELECT company FROM AC__Account WHERE ""Account Id"" = 30**" it should return a single field, in this case "company", and a single record, the #30.

When I use **command.ExecuteReader()** and check for **reader.FieldCount**, it returns correctly 1, if I check for rows using **reader.HasRows** it returns true, this is how I know, it received the data correctly.

Now, if I try to inspect the reader object by adding a breakpoint, and the ResultView (in this case, an Enumerable), instead of an enumerable I found an error as follow:
[image]

and inspecting the full StackTrace this is what I get

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode) at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetColAttributeStr(Int32 i, SQL_DESC v3FieldId, SQL_COLUMN v2FieldId, HANDLER handler) at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetName(Int32 i) at System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.BuildSchemaInfo() at System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.MoveNext() at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView.get_Items()
```

Is there a way to bypass Microsoft to get the metadata? or am I missing something? Please help, please check my code.

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(Conf.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:FilemakerPre1").Value))
        {

            string queryString = @"SELECT company FROM AC__Account WHERE ""Account Id"" = 30";

            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);
            
            connection.Open();

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            Console.WriteLine($"Field count: {reader.FieldCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Any rows?: {reader.HasRows}");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: try "SELECT company FROM AC__Account WHERE \"Account Id\" = 30"